# Nvidia Driver not being recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I have recently migrated from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 and I love it!
But I'm facing an issue when installing the Nvidia driver.
I have tried installing using the software and updates GUI and using the command line
by writing the following in order:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

From the list I picked the one that is recommended

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-495
```

and reboot my system, but when I type the following command:

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

I get:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I had to say one more piece of information. This happened after installing Steam and I had to install the following to make it work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnvidia-gl-440:i386 [reference][1]
```

but even after uninstalling all nvidi drivers with

```
$ sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')\
```

And reinstalling it as I mentioned above, I'm still facing the Nvidia driver couldn't be found issue

**EDIT:**
It seems that I have multiple versions when I'm printing the following command:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
rc  libnvidia-compute-455:amd64                 455.45.01-0ubuntu1                    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-460:amd64                 460.106.00-0ubuntu1                   amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-465:amd64                 465.19.01-0ubuntu1                    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                 470.82.00-0ubuntu0.20.04.1            amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-495:amd64                 495.29.05-0ubuntu1                    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-ml-dev                            10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) development files
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic  5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-27
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic  5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2+1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-40 (objects)
ii  nvidia-cuda-dev                             10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                             10.1.243-3                            all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                             10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Debugger (GDB)
ii  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                         10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit
ii  nvidia-opencl-dev:amd64                     10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL development files
ii  nvidia-profiler                             10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  nvidia-utils-495                            495.29.05-0ubuntu1                    amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-visual-profiler                      10.1.243-3                            amd64        NVIDIA Visual Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
```

These are not getting removed by the command I tried previously, so how can I remove them manually if this is in fact the root of the issue?

**EDIT**
This is what i see when i open additional drivers and i was able to manually remove all nvidia packages keeping nvidia-driver-495 only

[image]

Comment: The best time to install proprietary drivers would have been during the initial system installation by choosing 3rd party proprietary drivers and enabling downloading updates during install. After the fact, you can use `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` or you can enable them in the GUI "Software and Updates" settings under "Additional Drivers".

Comment: this didn't help